# Check all duplicate values in three-dimension array PHP

Tags: php

I have seen some answers here for multi-dimensional arrays but I cant find a solution for my problem.

I have this array, and its a three-dimensional array or anything you want to call it.

I need to check all duplicated `CodColaborador` and remove it from the array. I have tried the `in_array` but it only work for 1 level array I think.

Is there any simple way i can do it? I was trying and I was doing 4 `foreach` already and I think that would have a very bad performance!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CodColaborador] => 2159
                            [Nome] => Graça
                            [Sobrenome] => Almeida
                            [Ativo] => 1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CodColaborador] => 2159
                            [Nome] => Graça
                            [Sobrenome] => Almeida
                            [Ativo] => 1
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CodColaborador] => 681
                            [Nome] => Gonçalo Homem
                            [Sobrenome] => de Almeida Correia
                            [Ativo] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [CodColaborador] => 2159
                            [Nome] => Graça
                            [Sobrenome] => Almeida
                            [Ativo] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CodColaborador] => 2160
                            [Nome] => Fernando
                            [Sobrenome] => Melício
                            [Ativo] => 1
                        )

                )
....................
```

EDIT: just added another level in the array.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, please show `var_export()` of your array instead of `print_r()`;

Comment: I need to remove all duplicated values that are insinde the three-tier multidimensional array. The array has 25 values, and 12 are duplicates. Need to remove those 12 from that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check all duplicated CodColaborador and remove it from the array.

I don't know if you're looking to build a new multi-dimensional array, but in my code below I have assumed you meant remove it from the multi-dimensional array that holds the associative keys.

If you had something else in mind let me know, or alternatively you should be able to work it out from my solution.

**Try the following:**

```
$exists = [];

foreach($array as $key => $values) {

    foreach($values as $k => $v) {

        if(in_array($v['CodColaborador'], $exists)) unset($array[$key][$k]);

        $exists[] = $v['CodColaborador'];

    }

}
```

Essentially I'm looping through the array, then looping through the arrays within that array and I'm adding the `CodColaborador` value to an array I've called `$exists`. If the value already exists in this array, then it means it is a duplicate and I therefore unset it from the array (again, not sure which array you mean but I've gone with what I thought you meant).

Comment: It still puts out duplicated values. I think that only works for multi-dimension arrays. ````$array = array (0 => array(), 1 => array())```` The problem is that i have 2 levels of arrays ````$array = array (0 => array(0 => array(), 1=> array()), 1 => array(0 => array,))````

Comment: I made a small error in the previous code, this has been updated now, should remove from the original array.

Comment: Oh ye i notice that too, i changed it and i think its working fine, just need to figure something else out and i think its working. Thanks dude.

Comment: You're welcome - if you need anything else just drop a comment on here so I get a notification.

Comment: I made a mistake and i need to group them in another level, ill edit my question

Comment: That's fine, I'll have a look when it's been updated

Comment: i tried myself and i added another foreach but it wont work like it was doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207266/discussion-between-mark-overton-and-alexis-garcia).

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$data = [];
foreach ($array as $key1 => $array1) {
    foreach ($array1 as $key2 => $array2) {
        $data[] = $array2;
    }
}

$data = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not technically what you asked for, but if you have a fixed structure and order as you have you could crudely flatten and weed out duplicates, by overwriting.

Think here of just a huge list of key value pairs, loop through, use the name attribute as a key for the result, and change the key every time you find one.

This is only as good if your sub arrays have duplicate key value and it relies upon a unique attribute for the key.

Of course if a flattened result is not what you want then this is no use to you.  Doesn't matter how deeply nested the array is.

```
<?php
$data =
[
    [
        [
            'name' => 'John',
            'band' => 'Beatles'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Slash',
            'band' => 'Guns'
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'name' => 'Roger',
            'band' => 'Who'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Slash',
            'band' => 'Guns'
        ]
    ]
];

array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$result, &$key)
{
    if($k === 'name')
        $key = $v;
    $result[$key][$k] = $v;
});
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'John' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'John',
    'band' => 'Beatles',
  ),
  'Slash' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Slash',
    'band' => 'Guns',
  ),
  'Roger' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Roger',
    'band' => 'Who',
  ),
)
```